# Django - query multi-level foreign keys

Tags: python, django, django-views, foreign-keys

I am trying to understand the concept of querying multiple level foreign key tables in Django, and I really hope someone can help me with it.

So, I am trying to create a List view in Django which shows players, their scores and some related information like their level of expertise. The database structure is something like below:

```
Players Table
-------------
id
name
<field 1>
<field 2>
<field N>
```

Then there is a table which stores the player's scores

```
Player Scores Table
-------------------
id
player_id (this refers to player.id field from table above)
score
level_id (this refers to a level.id field from table below)
```

And there is a level table like below:

```
Level Table
-----------
id
level_text
```

What I want is to create a list like below:

```
Player Name   Player Score    Player Level
-----------   -------------   ------------
Blue_Marvel   10000           Maestro
Man_At_Arms   51              Noob
P_K_In_Debt   1230000         God
```

As you can guess the data for each of these three columns need to come from three different tables.

I am very new to Django and can only perform some basic queries. I know I can do `Player.object.all()` and I get all the players (there is a player model defined). Similarly I can do `Level.object.all()` and I get all the expertise levels.

However I am not sure how I can proceed to construct a list such as above with player name, score and level text.

Any help is appreciated. Assuming that there is a Level and Score model, is there an easy way for me to create above list? If these models are not available, does Django query have any nifty way to achieve this?

I would really be grateful for any pointers!

Comment: But every row maps on a `PlayerScore` row, right?

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you posted the actual models.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes every row maps to a player score. The score is shown for a particular gaming event.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - unfortunately, I dont even know where the models are located, this is a very legacy django app that was developed by many developers over time... I have come across  many models related to these tables.  I am trying to understand how to query these assuming the models are available

Comment: Well there is no way way you can write queries without knowing the models.

Answer (score 3):

For me, this looks like you want a `ListView` that actually maps on the `PlayerScore` table: for every row in the table there is *one* row in the output and vice versa.

The only think that makes this case more special, is that we want to fetch the player name as well. Typically you can do this by using a `.annotate(..)` on the values you want to select. So we can here define a [**`ListView`** [doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview):

```
# views.py

from django.db.models import F

class PlayerScoreListView(ListView):

    model = PlayerScore
    template = '/app/playerscore_list.html'
    queryset = PlayerScore.objects.annotate(
        player_name=F('player__name'),
        level_name=F('level__name')
    )
```

So each time we will also fetch the `player__name` column, as well as the `level__name. If you defined`player`and`level`as`ForeignKey`s to the`Player`model and`Level`model respectively, Django will automatically make the JOINs at database level, and these are stored in the`PlayerScore`instances as`.player_name`and`.level_name` attribute.

The only thing we still need to do, is define a template. For example:

```
{% app/templates/app/playerscore_list.html %}

<html>
<body>
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
     <th>Player name</th>
     <th>Score</th>
     <th>Level name</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 {% for item in object_list %}
  <tr>
     <td>{{ item.player_name }}</td>
     <td>{{ item.score }}</td>
     <td>{{ item.level_name }}</td>
  </tr>
 {% endfor %}
 </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course we also need to link a URL to this view:

```
# urls.py

from django.urls import path

from app.views import PlayerScoreListView

urlpatterns = [
    path('playerscore/', PlayerScoreListView.as_view(), name='playerscorelist'),
]
```

Of course the above is a "raw" implementation. In order to show all relevant content, and make the page look "*pleasant*", there still is some work to do.

Comment: I cant thank you enough for all your help! I will try this one out and let you know how it goes, thanks once again!